# Saddle point in pitchfork bifurcation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, chaos-theory, bifurcation

$$
\dot{x}  = \sigma(y-x) \\
\dot{y}  = r \ x - y - xz \\
\dot{z}  = -\beta z + xy 
$$
For a Lorentzian system, the node at (0,0,0) is stable for value of parameter $r<1$. I found that it turns in to a saddle node when $r$ is more than 1, i.e. i found that for $r>1$, some eigenvalues are more than 0 and some are less than zero. For example, one eigenvalue is always equal to $-\beta$, the other two are both negative for $r<1$ and then become of opposite signs for $r>1$. Many different sources state that biforcation at $r=1$ is a pitchfork biforcation. I though pitchfork biforcation has to have a stable node or an unstable node at the center. Is my result wrong or am I misunderstanding the pitchfork biforcation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an experiment consider the system 
$$\dot{x} = x(x^2-\lambda),\\ \dot{y} = \alpha y, \\ \dot{z} = \beta z.$$
When $\lambda = 0$ the system undergoes pitchfork bifurcation. Dynamics of each variable is independent from other variables, $Ox$ axis is a center manifold for equilibrium at $O$ when $\lambda = 0$. But you see that by choice of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ you can change what kind of equilibria you get after bifurcation. For a bifurcation it's important what happens on center manifold: this is what distinguishes one bifurcation from another.

Comment: So, in my specific case is that a supercritical pitchfork bifurcation?

Comment: Following [this convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitchfork_bifurcation#Supercritical_case) you have supercritical pitchfork: you increase parameter value and when passing through bifurcation value stable equilibrium becomes unstable and "spawns" two stable equilibrium (stability is meant along center manifold). I think that this is the case.

Comment: I realised I am a bit confused on the topic of stability. For a node to be stable, does it have to have all positive eigenvalues or does it have to have A positive eigenvalue? I.e. is saddle-node an unstable node? And in 3D, what is a node that has two positive and one negative eigenvalue, for example?

Comment: If all eigenvalues have negative real parts, then it is a stable hyperbolic (i.e. no eigenvalues with zero real part) equilibrium (usually it's called sink). If there is at least one eigenvalue with positive real part then the equilibrium is unstable. The difficult case is when all eigenvalues have non-positive real part (i.e., there are eigenvalues with zero real part): this requires reduction to a center manifold. Also [look at this](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Stability_of_equilibria).